# Call all string numbers in exploded array with wildcard

Tags: php, arrays, string, wildcard, explode

After you explode a string, you can call the individual delimited words using something like:

```
$string[0]
$string[1]
```

etc.

Is there a way to call them all at once with a wildcard. I know this example doesn't work but something like this:

```
$string[*]
```

It's probably a dumb question; I'm just trying to save myself having to do 30 lines of code instead of one.

-- EDIT --

Here's what I have right now that's working for me:

```
$words = explode(' ',$string);
$thestuff = '';
if ($words[0] || $words[1] || $words[2] || $words[3] || $words[4] || $words[5] || $words[6] || $words[7] || $words[8] || $words[9] || $words[10] || $words[11] || $words[12] || $words[13] || $words[14] || $words[15] || $words[16] || $words[17] || $words[18] || $words[19] || $words[20] || $words[21] || $words[22] || $words[23] || $words[24] || $words[25] || $words[26] || $words[27] || $words[28] || $words[29] || $words[30]){
    $thestuff = do_shortcode($content);
}
return $thestuff;
}
```

But I'd like to be able to do it with $words[wildcard] or something simpler.

Comment: Yes, sorry. PHP. Yes, I know I'm dealing with arrays. I've been scouring; just haven't found anything on wildcards for the numbers.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do with them?  You cannot wildcard the indices, but there is probably something else that will do what you want.

Comment: I've updated the post to explain better what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just check the length of `$words`?

Comment: I don't think that would help with what I'm trying to do. Basically, I'm looking for a catch-all. It may not be possible the way I'm currently approaching it.

Comment: 30 is an arbitrary limit, just trying to account for more than anyone would ever input into the string. $words[1-30] obviously didn't work either.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what it is exactly you are trying to do. If you are using this to check for the existence of a space in the original string, why not just use `preg_match()`? If it is something else, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I'll elaborate. I'm not checking for spaces. The actual code is if(current_user_can($roles[0]) || current_user_can($roles[1]) etc. $role is the attribute in the shortcode where they enter a string of user roles, it then gets exploded into $roles. The way this works, it only shows the shortcode content to the user roles defined in the string, with an arbitrary limit of 30 space-delimited values in the string.

Comment: So I'm looking for a way to (1) remove that arbitrary limit and more importantly (2) make the code simpler.

Comment: 1) run your `$roles` through a `for` loop. 2) see 1. The regular way to do permission-type things is with bitwise operations, but the best you will get away with here without significant changes is to iterate over every member of `$roles` and pass it to `current_user_can()`.

Comment: Right. That makes sense. 1) I'll investigate for loops and see if I can figure that out. I'm new to this. 2) I'm trying to design it so it accounts for custom roles, which is why I'm doing it this way rather then passing "administrator" and "editor" etc. to current_user_can(). I wouldn't know where to begin with bitwise. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wow. I just did it using foreach ($roles as $value) and threw $value into current_user_can(). Works perfectly. So simple. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code. You are using OR conditions so that you don't need to check every index.

```
$words = explode(' ',$string);
$thestuff = '';
if (isset($words[0]) && !empty($words[0])){
    $thestuff = do_shortcode($content);
}
return $thestuff;
}
```